# How to export emacs calfw calendar to live html?

Tags: html, emacs, export

I can export org-mode files to an HTML file just fine using:

- `C-c C-e`
- `h`
- `h`

However, when I display calw calendar in the buffer using `M-x cfw:open-calendar-buffer`, then try to run the export above, `C-c C-e is undefined`. I imagine this has something to do with `Calendar-mode`, but I'm not sure how to enforce HTML export in this mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if there is anything built-in, but that sure would be great if it were possible!  `calendar-mode` has a *related* library that can generate different types of exports (html, latex/pdf, etc.), and it is possible to add entries in addition to the holidays -- so that is probably the easier option if there is nothing special for calfw to meet your precise needs.

Comment: I really want Calfw because I can populate the calendar with events. Would love to display the calendar, agenda, and todo list on a website for my family to view. Would really love to embed a term in the page so they could add events too!

Comment: The raw data (used by Calfw and org-agenda) in the form of a list can be extracted with this:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287 and that data can be put into a form that is already supported by the related built-in calendar library capable of generating html and pdf, just like the holidays that already appear; e.g., `cal-tex` and `cal-html`.

Comment: @lawlist Can you indicate how to pass that info to `cal-tex`?  I tried replacing `cal-tex-list-diary-entries` with your function and turn `cal-tex-diary` on, but this fails.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël -- I would suggest writing up a separate question and then either myself or another forum participant can take a look at it.  It will be necessary to examine the data structure of the gathered data and convert it to whatever `cal-tex` uses ... e.g., a list containing the description and applicable date/time.  The gathered data may need to be sorted if there are multiple entries on the same day that need to be in order of time (earliest to the latest) .... the linked function used to gather the data *may* already be able to sort with the proper let-bound variable sorting strategy ....